# How do i show this White’s heteroscedastic consistent estimates of the model and produce a table with the coefficients?

Tags: r

I am trying to do the estimate with my code looking like this

```
library(sandwich)
estimate = fit$coefficients
cvox.max = vcovHC(fit)
std.error = sqrt(diag(cvox.max))
t.statistic = estimate/std.error
p.value = 2*(1-pt(abs(t.statistic), 2949))
CI = confint(fit, error_format= "95 % CI [{conf.low}, {conf.high}]")
table.cp = cbind(estimate, std.error, t.statistic. p.value, CI)
knitr::kable(table.cp)
```

However, I keep getting the error code -

> Error: unexpected symbol in "table.cp = cbind(estimate, std.error, t.statistic. p.value"

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have a typo in `cbind` instead of `,` you have a `.` after `t.statistic`.

Comment: My mistake. Thank you